# Change sort asc & desc onclick on two button to sort onclick on one button - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. I have two button for sort. But I want to change for sort both ascending and descending in one button.

```
 // sort asc
  const onSortA = (e) => {
    let uname = [...userdata];

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "name":
        uname = uname.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name);
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  // sort desc
  const onSortD = (e) => {
    let uname = [...userdata];

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "name":
        uname = uname.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name);
        uname.reverse();
        break;   
      default:
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the sort state data in in-app state and use that to toggle the single button value and onClick handle function call

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [userdata, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [ascId, setAscSortId] = useState(true);
  const [ascFullname, setAscSortFullname] = useState(true);

...............

const onAscSort = (e) => {
...............
switch (e.target.id) {
      case "id":
           setAscSortId(false);
      case "fullname":
           setAscSortFullname(false);
...............
    setUserData(userdetail);
  };

const onDescSort = (e) => {
...............
switch (e.target.id) {
      case "id":
           setAscSortId(true);
      case "fullname":
           setAscSortFullname(true);
...............
    setUserData(userdetail);
  };
```

```
<button type="button" id="id" onClick={(e) => ascId ? onAscSortId(e) : onDescSortId(e)} /> { ascId ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' } </button>
<button type="button" id="fullname" onClick={(e) => ascFullname ? onAscSortFullname(e) : onDescSortFullname(e)} /> { ascFullname ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' } </button>
```

Comment: It's working fine but both column button will change it's state(ASC to DESC) if onclick on one of the column button. Is there any step to ensure that doesnt happen?

Comment: Do you have 2 columns each with asc/decs button?

Comment: Yes, as I have column ID and Full Name. I didn't remove the code that I posted, I just add the state for asc to true and false

Comment: ok, I updated the code, just you need to have 1 more state

Answer (score 0):

You can use up and down arrow fromt font awesome library https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

```
<>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLongArrowAltUp} className="sort-arrow" onClick={onAscSort}/>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLongArrowAltDown} className="sort-arrow"  onClick={onDesSort} />
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle sort order in state and then use `React.useEffect` to sort through your data on order change, eliminating multiple functions and code duplication. Here's and example with ID sorting, based on your provided code:

```
import React from 'react';

const FIELDS = {
    ID: 'id',
    FULL_NAME: 'fullname',
};

const SORT_ORDER = {
    ASC: 'ASC',
    DESC: 'DESC',
};

const SORT_ORDER_TOGGLE = {
    [SORT_ORDER.ASC]: SORT_ORDER.DESC,
    [SORT_ORDER.DESC]: SORT_ORDER.ASC,
};

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [userdata, setUserData] = React.useState([]);
    const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = React.useState({
        field: FIELDS.ID,
        order: SORT_ORDER.ASC,
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let updatedUserData = [...userdata];

        switch (sortOrder.id) {
            case FIELDS.ID:
                updatedUserData = userdata.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
                break;
            case FIELDS.FULL_NAME:
                updatedUserData = userdata.sort((a, b) => a.fullname.localeCompare(b.fullname));
                break;
            default:
        }

        if (sortOrder.order === SORT_ORDER.DESC) {
            updatedUserData.reverse();
        }

        setUserData(updatedUserData);
    }, [sortOrder.order]);

    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            id="id"
            onClick={ (e) => setSortOrder((prevOrder) => ({
                field: e.target.id,
                order: SORT_ORDER_TOGGLE[prevOrder.order],
            })) }
        >
            { sortOrder.order }
        </button>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```